# Asp.net core MVC jquery Autcomplete returning blank data rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've been struggling with this issue for a while. I have started using ASP.NET Core and am building an ASP.NET Core MVC project. I'm having an issue with the JQuery autocomplete widget returning blank data from a query.

Here is my code:

html view:

```
@section Scripts{

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Requests")',
dataType: "json",
data: { search: $("#searchInput").val() },
success: function (data) {
response($.map(data, function (item) {
return { label: item.NameString};
}));
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
alert("Error");
}
});
}
});

</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSearchValue(string search)
    {
        var allsearch = _context.Requests.Where(x => x.NameString.ToLower().Contains(search)).Select(x => new Requests
        {
            NameString = x.NameString,
        }).ToList();
        return Ok(allsearch);
    }
```

It appears as though the JQuery is returning the correct amount of suggestions, however, they are blank. So it has to be that `NameString` in the JQuery is not being passed correctly, but I cannot work out how to do it.

Comment: Return JSON data from your controller code.`return Json(new {data=allsearch});`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have made the changes but unfortunately it is still returning blank data...

Comment: @Abhishek really appreciate any guidance that you can give me

Comment: @Abhishek I have replaced return "Ok(allsearch);" with your suggestion "return Json(new {data=allsearch});" in the controller. Haven't changed anything in the View. Still returning blank data rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
        return item.nameString;
      }));
```

instead of

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
return { label: item.NameString};
}));
```

It will work.

Comment: @KarthickAmbikapthi it works! thank you so much. Once I returned the controller to the original code i.e. return Ok(allsearch); and changed View code to as you suggested above it works. Thanks again!